# Can you Accio a person?

Tags: harry-potter

What are the boundaries of the Accio spell/Summoning Charm? Can you Accio people? Random items? Other people's wands?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Good question, but it already has an answer linked above. In the meantime, feel free to checkout our [tour] and have a look at our [help].